# React renders repeatedly on event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, react-hooks

I'm using sockets in my website and there's an event where one user can send a word to the server, which emits (`art-addpic`) an image URL corresponding to that word to everyone, but only the user with `isArtist=true` gets to respond to the event.
The artist's page is supposed to update an existing list of image URLs (`optionImages`) with the received URL once. But when the event is received, all images in the list are replaced by the received URL. Furthermore, the component rendering the list of images `ArtBoard` is not re-rendered with updated URLs.
I'm new to React. Where am I going wrong?

I've checked the server and the event `art-addpic` is broadcasted only once.

Arena.js: (The webpage where this happens):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Leaderboard from "../comps/Leaderboard";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Service from "../Service";
import DetBoard from "../comps/DetBoard";
import ArtBoard from "../comps/ArtBoard";
const username = "Nick"
const roomkey="abc"
let userid;
if(localStorage.getItem('userid')){
    userid = localStorage.getItem('userid')
}
else{
    userid = Service.makeid(5);
    localStorage.setItem('userid', userid);
}
function useForceUpdate(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // integer state
    return () => setValue(value => value + 1); // update the state to force render
}
// const [userid,setUserId] = 
const socket = io('http://localhost:3001', {query:"username="+username+"&roomkey="+roomkey+"&userid="+userid});
const Arena = (props)=>{
    const [isArtist, setIsArtist] = useState(false);
    const [focusImage, setFocusImage] = useState('https://i.imgur.com/61HsZCU.jpeg')
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [optionImages, setOptionImages] = useState([
        'https://i.imgur.com/61HsZCU.jpeg',
        'https://i.imgur.com/61HsZCU.jpeg',
        'https://i.imgur.com/61HsZCU.jpeg',
        'https://i.imgur.com/61HsZCU.jpeg',
        'https://i.imgur.com/61HsZCU.jpeg'
    ])
    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on('connect',()=>{
            console.log("connected")
        })
        socket.on('players', (data)=>{
            data = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(data)
            setPlayers(data)
        })
        socket.on('artist', (data)=>{
            if(data===userid){
                console.log('You are an artist, Mr White.')
                setIsArtist(true);
            }
            else{
                setIsArtist(false);
            }
        })    
        socket.on('art-addpic', (data)=>{
            data = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(data)
            let tempOps =optionImages;
            tempOps.splice(0, 1);
            tempOps.push(data.url)
            console.log(tempOps)
            setOptionImages(tempOps);
        })
    }, [
        optionImages
    ]);
    if(isArtist){
        return(
            <div>
            <Leaderboard players={players}></Leaderboard>
            {/* <ArtBoard></ArtBoard> */}
            <ArtBoard socket={socket} focusImage={focusImage} optionImages={optionImages} setOptionImages={setOptionImages}/>         
        </div>
        );
    }
    else{
        return (
            <div>
            <Leaderboard players={players}></Leaderboard>
            {/* <ArtBoard></ArtBoard> */}
            <DetBoard socket={socket} focusImage={focusImage}/>         
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Arena;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've at least a few issues:

1. No clean up function returned from the `useEffect` hook to unsubscribe the socket connections, so they remain open.
2. `optionImages` state mutations.
3. Updating the `optionImages` state retriggers the `useEffect` callback which creates more subscriptions.

Hook Code

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });

  socket.on('players', (data) => {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    setPlayers(data);
  });

  socket.on('artist', (data) => {
    if (data === userid) {
      console.log('You are an artist, Mr White.');
      setIsArtist(true);
    } else {
      setIsArtist(false);
    }
  });

  socket.on('art-addpic', (data) => {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    let tempOps = optionImages; // (2) tempOps is reference to optionImages state
    tempOps.splice(0, 1);   // (2) mutation!
    tempOps.push(data.url); // (2) mutation!
    console.log(tempOps);
    setOptionImages(tempOps); // (2,3) saved state reference back into state
  });

  // (1) missing cleanup function
}, [optionImages]); // (3) state updated in hook
```

From what I can tell, the main issue is with the `'art-addpic'` event. It seems like you want to remove the first element from the `optionImages` state and add a new URL to the end.

If this is the case then I have the following suggestions:

1. Return a cleanup function to unsubscribe the socket connections.
2. Remove all `useEffect` hook dependencies so the hook run once when the component mounts to establish the socket subscriptions, and clean them up when unmounting.
3. Use a functional state update for `optionImages` to remove the state as an external dependency.

Hook Code

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });

  socket.on('players', (data) => {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsedData);
    setPlayers(parsedData);
  });

  socket.on('artist', (data) => {
    setIsArtist(data === userid);
  });

  socket.on('art-addpic', (data) => {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsedData);

    setOptionImages(optionImages => 
      // Shallow copy into array, append URL, slice & keep last 4 elements
      [...optionImages, parsedData.url].slice(-4),
    );
  });

  return () => {
    socket.removeAllListeners();
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isArtist) {
    console.log('You are an artist, Mr White.');
  }
}, [isArtist]);
```